# Thymeleaf: add CSS offline

Tags: spring-boot, pdf-generation, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf to generate PDF in background processes (batch) using Spring Boot 2...

To add some style to my PDF's I would like to add some CSS using this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/CDM.css" th:href="@{/static/css/CDM.css}"/>
```

Then I got the following exception :

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/static/css/CDM.css" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface
```

I've seen this [issue on github](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springmail/issues/2) but I don't get how I could get a WebContext in a batch process?

Do anyone know how I could load my CSS files so that they are applied in my PDF?

Thanks!

Comment: And what if you remove the th:href and just use the plain href that point relative to the css?

Comment: When I do this :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/CDM.css"/> . No CSS is applied to my PDF

Comment: have a look at your class path. Is it really static/css/CDM.css ?

Comment: Yes. It is :-(.   Thymeleaf can fin my templates that are under templates/...